# UpdateAlias in c# elastic search .net client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-6.0

I am using .NET client for elastic search.
I am trying to write an update alias call after indexing a few documents which are working fine. But when I am trying to write Update Alias code i am getting all kinds of compilation errors mostly as I am not familiar with c# language syntax.

Following is the piece of code I am trying to compile:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Company Namespace;
using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch;
using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.IndexManagement;
using Action = Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.IndexManagement.Action;

public Task<UpdateAliasesResponse> UpdateAlias(string indexName)
        {
            var addAction = new AddAction();
            addAction.Index = IndexName.From<string>(indexName);
            addAction.Alias = new IndexAlias(ALIAS_NAME);
            var actions = new Collection<Action>();
            actions.Add(addAction);
            UpdateAliasesRequest request = new UpdateAliasesRequest();
            request.Actions = actions;

            // request.Actions = actions;
            return this._elasticsearchClient.Indices.UpdateAliasesAsync(request);
        }
```

The given code may not even compile at all. I followed the documentation page there are no reference guide for .net sdk

sdk:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch" Version="8.11.0" />
```

Error:

```
Error CS1729 : 'IndexAlias' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

Comment: With my very limited reading in the .NET Clients section of Elastic - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/aliasing.html It seems like you have to remove the Alias and then readd it again. I found the constructor you're having issues with and its an internal but I also think this is much older code that doesn't really work anymore. Apologies, but the code to add and readd is in the link I sent. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this doc points to 1.x when i change it to 8.9 it alerts with message `This page is not available in the docs for version:8.9`